# Can't open perl script "/bin/verilator" during 'make test'

Tags: linux, perl, terminal, root, verilator

I'm following a tutorial to install a program on an RHEL environment and I've overcome some errors up until this point. I'm at the end of the installation process, attempting to confirm the validity through "make test", which returns the following error:

```
[user@localhost verilator-4.018]$ make test
Can't open perl script "/bin/verilator": No such file or directory
...
[Makefile:228: smoke-test] Error 10
```

I first checked to see if there was a verilator-4.018/bin/verilator file, which there was.

I then tried researching the error online and got a single result, where a user stated the issue could be solved by "Setting VERILATOR_ROOT to the root of your checkout", but I'm not too sure how to interpret this since I'm a beginner.

I tried setting as root:

```
[root@localhost verilator-4.018]# make test
```

But got the same error messages.

Also, please let me know how I can rephrase the title to make it more specific. I thought it was difficult to be specific about a question where I need interpretation help.

Comment: You should file a bug report against verilator. `make test` should just work. Multiple users should not be experiencing problems. It is the maintainer's responsibility to ensure that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no /bin/verilator ... there is `bin/verilator`. But it's more tricky than that : The tests are done with `test_regress/driver.pl`, so "bin/verilator" is one level up.

Edit `test_regress/driver.pl`, line 782 to

```
   my @cmdargs = ("perl", "$ENV{VERILATOR_ROOT}../bin/verilator",
```

... and the firsts tests can be run.

More bugs : "smoke-test" fails : Will use a file from the install destination. Please do `# make install` ... and the next tests can also be run.

Test result → `make-test__result.txt` https://www.dropbox.com/s/tebcqj7bl5dkzx8/make-test__result.txt?dl=0

Please notice the SYSTEMC settings. `verilator` was built with `$ export SYSTEMC_INCLUDE=/usr/local/include/ && export SYSTEMC_LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib-linux64 && ./configure && make`

SYSTEMC is required for the tests to pass. See `verilator/README`

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried following this and changing it to verilator-4.018/bin/verilator but the issue persists...

Comment: Desktop/verilator-4.018/test_regress/driver.pl. Line 782 "{VERILATOR_ROOT}verilator-4.018/bin/verilator",

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/tyBTEAq.png

Comment: Please read my answer : It must be `my @cmdargs = ("perl", "$ENV{VERILATOR_ROOT}../bin/verilator",` .... I.e. the two periods is "one level up".

Comment: Yes that solved it! I got confused thinking the ".." symbolized going 'out' one directory. Thanks so much!